# Angular FormGroup - Automatically divide value from another field by 100

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, calculated-field

I have 3 fields in an angular form group and one of the fields is basically a tool for the user that divides the value from another field automatically. So, the user types in a number and the other field automatically displays that value divided by 100.

It looks like this:

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
        Buildyear:           new FormControl(this.buildyear, [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)]),
        Areasize:            new FormControl(this.areasize, [Validators.required] ),
        Areasize_divided:    new FormControl(''),
     });
```

"Areasize_divided" automatically divides the value that's inside "Areasize", by default there's already a value in that field but if the user types in a new value into "Areasize" that should be automatically calculated in "Areasize_divided" as well. And the other way around, if the user types in a value into "Areasize_divided" it will automatically multiply "Areasize" by 100.

What would be the best way of achieving something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen on form control changes and update your other control accordingly.

```
formGroup.get('Areasize')
  .valueChanges
  .subscribe(value => formGroup
    .get('Areasize_divided')
    .setValue(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value / 100)
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Would it be advisable to implement this in ngOninit()? Or a seperate function?

Comment: @bobdolan you should do it when you want : you can even create a button `automatically divide by 100` if you want.

Comment: @bobdolan but if i had to do it, I would do it right after creating my form.

Comment: Okay I'll try it out. It's important that the form field automatically updates the value without the user having to click on a button. I'm not quite sure how I could achieve this

Comment: You should set your control to disabled (so that the user doesn't input it himself) and use that piece of code right after creating the form. But again, that's my mere opinion, it highly depends on your project !

Comment: Thank you. The user should be able to put values into both fields, since both of these fields calculate each other. Areasize_divided will multiply Areasize by 100 and the other way around as I described in my problem (should've made it clearer in the question, I will do so now).

Comment: Well I assume you can do the other way around with what I gave you ;)

Comment: Thank you, yes I found a solution with the help of your contribution :)